# Reading from file into 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying to read a 20x20 maze from a .txt file into a 2D array.
Because fgets also reads the NUL and \n, I left room for 22 characters per row (20 for maze).

However, it does not work the way I intended.

When I tested this code to print just a single array (maze[0] for example), it seems that the whole file is copied into a single array.

What have I done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFLEN 22

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen ("maze.txt", "r"); 
    char maze[22][20];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        fgets(maze[i], BUFLEN, fp);
    }
    for (j=0; j<20; j++){
        printf("%s", maze[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `char maze[22][20];` --> `char maze[20][22];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared your datatype backwards.  You need:

```
char maze[20][BUFLEN];
```

That will give you 20 "rows" of `BUFLEN` characters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have an array of 20 buffers of size 22, you have to declare an array `char maze[20][22];`, not `char maze[22][20];`, as this will show you all the strings displaced by `2*row_index` characters as you walk the array.

Second, if you have defined a constant with `#define BUFLEN 22`, **please, use it** defining `char maze[20][BUFLEN];` instead.  This will save you a lot of trouble if you decide to change the constant later on.  This is the use the constants are defined to.

Third, as you have done with `BUFLEN` you could have done with `MAZESIZE`, yielding to:

```
#define MAZESIZE 20
#define BUFFSIZE ((MAZESIZE) + 2) /* to allow for \n and \0 chars. */
...
char maze[MAZESIZE][BUFSIZE];
```

then, you can change the `MAZESIZE` constant (or the `BUFFSIZE`, case you decide to eliminate the `'\n'` later), without having to look where you use it.